# In Backbone, can I add model behavior to a collection?

Tags: javascript, architecture, backbone.js, publish-subscribe

If I have a collection of objects, but also want to store some higher-level information about those objects, is it appropriate to add some model behavior to the collection?

In my situation, I'm looking for a collection of application paths to have a bool field called 'curPath'. If it's changed, the collection should set a flag that indicates the current page. This way outside observers only have to observe one field, not every model in the path collection.

Here's what that might look like:

```
var PathModel = Backbone.Model.extend({})
var PathCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function(){ this.model = PathModel }
})
// I want to be able to set observable properties on the collection, so...
var PathManager = _.extend(Backbone.Model, PathCollection)

// Then maybe I can do something like this?
PathManager.each(function(pathModel){
  pathModel.on('change:curPath', function(m, value, o){
    // I mean for 'this'.set to point to the instance of the PathManager
    if (value === true){ this.set('curPath', pathModel.get('id')) } 
  }, this)
}, this)
```

Is it appropriate to add observable behavior to a collection (collection+model > model), or do I need to add a wrapping model to the whole thing (model > collection > model), or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of the methods on Model and Collection have the same names that will cause conflicts and possible problems with updating to future versions of Backbone could occur I would advise against this pattern. Rather then doing that create a PathManager class and have PathCollection be initialized and set it as paths property on this model. If from what you are saying

```
var PathManager = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.paths = new PathCollection();
    }
});

var pathManager = new PathManager();

pathManager.paths.add({ /* new path */ });
pathManager.on('change', doSomething);
pathManager.paths.on('add', doSomethingElse);
```

I'd do it something like this

Comment: PathManager is a model.  Should "paths" be an attribute that you access/set via the get/set methods, rather than properties of the object itself?  Or are they already (backbone clueless)?  Not saying there is any advantage either way that I understand (for example, I don't think change events would not fire were it a get/set attribute).  I am just trying to work out what is normal practice?

Comment: I would advise against putting it as a model attribute and rather keep it as a property as shown in the example. 
If you'd like to nest collections/models as attributes I'd recommend reading more about relational plugins for backbone to ensure proper syncing and such.